# Curtain Rod for Vertical Blinds

Tags: windows, blinds, curtain-rail

I have typical Vertical Blinds which look like this below, with Valence and headrail. What kind of Curtain rod would I need, since I like extra insulation during the winters. My headrail extends 5 inches out from the wall, and actual vanes extend 4 inches from the wall.

Many curtain rods at the store, do not extend out this far.

If I remove the valence decorative cover on the headrail, it looks kind of strange.

[image]

Comment: It is usually curtains or blinds, not often found together.  Might need to make something with shelf brackets to hold curtain rod.  A shelf with a drop down edge?

Comment: I cover my window with a plastic sheet under my vertical blind for the winter. It helps unless you want to keep the window operatable throughout the cold season.

Comment: hi @r13 what if you want to open your windows occasionally? does the plastic sheet have to be removed?

Comment: I don't remove the sheet completely, usually roll the sheet 1/3 way up then recover the window with the same sheet and tape. The type will be there unless repeating the opening -retaping too frequently.

Comment: what do you think is better for insulation? @r13 home insulation kit, or light-translucent sheer curtain.  , thanks

Comment: You have to find a way to hang your curtain first. Then, the window kit blocks out the transmitting path of the cold entirely, can the curtain do it?

Comment: not sure, the window kit insulation plastic sheet is that strong? I didn't know that, @r13

Comment: Positive, after more than two decades of experience with it. It is perfect for DIY, after heating (use a hairdryer) it to perfect flat, you will be proud of yourself. Of course, it is weak in puncher and slicing by sharp objects and melts in fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need either a very shallow bracket to hold the curtain *behind* the blinds (if there's room) or a very deep bracket to hold the curtain *in front of* the blinds.

You might need to get creative and use shelving brackets if you cannot find actual curtain brackets deep enough. Often, the shelving brackets aren't particularly attractive, so you could cover them with some wood to box them in and make them look nicer.

Comment: Wow... appreciate the quick check mark. Feel free to place it somewhere else if a better answer comes along.